# how to get an address from google map api from lat and lon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I get the lat and lon based on user location. how can I get the address by lat and lon utilizing google map api?

and show it on client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) to get the address by reverse geocoding.  There are several examples in the [Samples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html) section of the Google Maps Documentation.